# SFML and OpenGL causes GL_INVALID_OPERATIONS when calling the draw function

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

I am working on a small game engine on my main computer, but when i cloned the project on my laptop I just get a lot of error messages and displays a blank screen.

Here are some of the error messages I am getting every frame from calling the SFML draw function:

```
Warning: The created OpenGL context does not fully meet the settings that were requested
Requested: version = 4.4 ; depth bits = 24 ; stencil bits = 8 ; AA level = 1 ; core = false ; debug = false ; sRGB = false
Created: version = 4.5 ; depth bits = 24 ; stencil bits = 8 ; AA level = 4 ; core = true ; debug = false ; sRGB = false
An internal OpenGL call failed in RenderTarget.cpp(369).
Expression:
   GLEXT_glClientActiveTexture(GLEXT_GL_TEXTURE0)
Error description:
   GL_INVALID_OPERATION
   The specified operation is not allowed in the current state.

An internal OpenGL call failed in RenderTarget.cpp(375).
Expression:
   glDisable(GL_LIGHTING)
Error description:
   GL_INVALID_ENUM
   An unacceptable value has been specified for an enumerated argument.

An internal OpenGL call failed in RenderTarget.cpp(377).
Expression:
   glDisable(GL_ALPHA_TEST)
Error description:
   GL_INVALID_ENUM
   An unacceptable value has been specified for an enumerated argument.

An internal OpenGL call failed in RenderTarget.cpp(378).
Expression:
   glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
Error description:
   GL_INVALID_ENUM
   An unacceptable value has been specified for an enumerated argument.

An internal OpenGL call failed in RenderTarget.cpp(380).
Expression:
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
Error description:
   GL_INVALID_OPERATION
   The specified operation is not allowed in the current state.

An internal OpenGL call failed in RenderTarget.cpp(381).
Expression:
   glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
Error description:
   GL_INVALID_OPERATION
   The specified operation is not allowed in the current state.
```

I am simply drawing sprites and textures in the menu screen, and it seems like even the OpenGL functions to draw also produces errors. Here's the link to my github repo: https://github.com/ZzkilzZ/mfengine

I am running the LTS version of Ubuntu on both my computers, and what i think it might be is a discrepancy in the versions of certain dependencies?

EDIT:
These are my glxinfo results:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.0.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 19.0.8
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 19.0.8
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

I am running Ubuntu 18.4 LTS

Comment: What GPU and OS are you running on?

Comment: I added the result of glxinfo, it sais I should be able to use 4.5 :/

Comment: It says that you are able to use 4.5 **Core Profile**, not compatibility.

Comment: It says the same except 4.6 on my other computer which runs fine :/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you to @SurvivalMachine and @derhass for your help!
I eventually downgraded the opengl all the way down to version 3.0 and glsl down to 130 core and got the menu screen working again. It loads everything but the shaders but i suspect this is the result of me using more modern functions. I am giving up on older computers, this seems like too much of a sacrifice just for 2015 computers to work :D

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an OpenGL Core Profile context, but the code uses legacy fixed-function stuff like `glDisable(GL_LIGHTING)`. The solution is to request a compatiblity profile when creating the context. It depends on your OpenGL implementation if compatibility profile is available. I suggest you find a more modern example code.

It looks like that Compatibility Profile can be set in SFML's `sf::ContextSettings::attributeFlags` or

```
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR,4);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR,5);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE,GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE);
```

Comment: It seems like it's SFML calling those functions... Thank you, I'll try that out!

Comment: Why am i only getting the errors on one computer and not the other tho?

Comment: @ZzkilzZ maybe your other computer's OpenGL implementation defaults to compatibility profile.

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to force a different profile? It there a way i could request an other profile during my glew initialization?

Comment: @ZzkilzZ I expanded my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I tested changing the attribute flags and also tried other opengl loaders. I tried using different combinations of core and compatibility but SFML keeps changing my settings from compatibility to core by default... This is making me crazy!

Comment: @ZzkilzZ that is most likely due to your GL implementation not supporting the compatibility profile. You request GL 4.x, but you are probably limited to GL 2.1 or 3.0 if you want to use legacy features.

Comment: `OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 19.0.8` so it's 3.0 at most if you don't use a core profile.

Comment: My other computer on which it runs fine has 3.2 , but isn't that OpenGL ES?